# How to find a word in a string that exists in an array using ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have an array and I want to find out if any of the words in the array are in a string. I can do that with traditional JavaScript but how would I do that using ES6 constructs?

Example:

```
 var wordsInTheStringArray = ["red", "green", "blue"].filter(word => "the red cat. the green gopher.");
 wordsInTheStringArray; // ["red", "green"]
```

Classic Method:

```
var words = ["red", "green", "blue"]
var string = "the red cat. the green gopher.";
var found = [];

for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
     var hasWord = string.indexOf(words[i])!=-1;
     hasWord ? found.push(words[i]) : 0;
}

console.log(found);
```

Comment: how do you do it with classic javascript?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense, where does `green` come from in the result? Please show us how you'd do it with "traditional JavaScript".

Comment: Maybe you meant `.filter(word => "the red cat".includes(word));`? (Admittedly that matches any substrings, not whole words)

Comment: @Bergi Right! I updated the post. The string should have red and green in it.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have wrote the code for classic method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look for strings in the string.

```js
var wordsInTheStringArray = ["red", "green", "blue"].filter(word => "the red cat. the green gopher.".includes(word));
console.log(wordsInTheStringArray);
```

To look for *words* in the string: (`greener` will not count)

```js
var wordsInTheStringArray = ["red", "green", "blue"].filter(word => "the red cat is not greener".split(' ').includes(word));
console.log(wordsInTheStringArray);
```

Checking for punctuation in words: (`red.` will count)

```js
var wordsInTheStringArray = ["red", "green", "blue"].filter(word => "the cat is red.".split(' ').map(w => w.split('').filter(l => ![".","\,"].includes(l)).join('')).includes(word));
console.log(wordsInTheStringArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, not sure that I do, you can use sets to find the intersections of the words.

```
const wordsInTheStringArray = ["red", "green", "blue"];
const words = "the red and green cat";
const wordsSplit = words.split(" ");

const matches = wordsInTheStringArray.filter(word => new Set(wordsSplit).has(word));
```

That would give you the following result

```
["red", "green"]
```

Comment: looks a bit overcomplicated, because you create always a new `Set` without need.